# how to decrease LOSS in Word2Vec model on tensorflow

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, word2vec

I try to run the word2vec model. it's working but I confused why loss never decrease. it always keeps about 300.

please give me some tips about why it happened and how to fix it.

[output view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGiwX.png)

I paste a part of code about the graph, hoped it is helpful.

```
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    train_inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size],name='train_inputs')
    train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, 1],name='train_labels')
    valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_examples, dtype=tf.int32)


    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        with tf.name_scope('Embeddings'):
            embeddings = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([vocabulary_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0),name='Embeddings')
            embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, train_inputs)
            tf.summary.histogram(name ='Embeddings', values = embeddings)

        with tf.name_scope('Weights'):
            nce_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([vocabulary_size, embedding_size],stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(embedding_size)),name='Weights')
            tf.summary.histogram(name ='Weights', values = nce_weights)

        with tf.name_scope('Biases'):
            nce_biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([vocabulary_size]),dtype=tf.float32,name='Biases')
            tf.summary.histogram(name ='Biases', values = nce_biases)

    with tf.name_scope('Loss'):
        output_layer = tf.nn.nce_loss(weights=nce_weights,
                                  biases=nce_biases,
                                  inputs=embed,
                                  labels=train_labels,
                                  num_sampled=num_sampled,
                                  num_classes=vocabulary_size)
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(output_layer)
        tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss)

    with tf.name_scope('Optimizer'):
        #optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1.0).minimize(loss)
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1.0).minimize(loss)

    with tf.name_scope('normalized'):
        norm = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(embeddings), 1, keep_dims=True))
        normalized_embeddings = embeddings / norm
        valid_embeddings = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(normalized_embeddings, valid_dataset)
    merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

then the training step is like this:

```
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
# We must initialize all variables before we use them.
    init.run()
    logging.info("Initialized")
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("TB/", graph = sess.graph)#TensorBoard
    for step in xrange(num_steps):
        batch_inputs, batch_labels = generate_batch(batch_size, num_skips, skip_window)


        nextDict = {train_inputs: batch_inputs, train_labels: batch_labels}

        stepMerged,stepLoss = sess.run([merged,loss],feed_dict=nextDict)
        logging.info("loss for this step("+str(step)+"):"+str(float(stepLoss)))
```

---

**EDIT 1:**

I screenshot the TensorBoard report, but it's temporarily because training continues.

now Training steps had passed the 120k times(the plan is 200K), about 22 hours.

[temporarily loss report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riA5j.png)

Comment: my training sets process from the newspaper's content in Mandarin. cutting word step uses the jieba lib.       a possible reason is a lot of rare words?

Comment: Can you show the actual loss values reported? If loss *never* decreases, that would indicate some problem. But if it decreases for a while, but then reaches a plateau (with slight up/down changes), that can be normal. It means a model has gotten about as good as it can over the whole training set. (At that point, getting any better – reducing loss – on one example makes another worse, and vice versa.)

Comment: @gojomo thanks for the comment. I try to update the screenshot of  TensorBoard loss report. the loss value is about 290 - 320, this could be called "with slight up/down changes"?

Comment: You'd need to watch the values over time, and specifically how they change from one full pass over the training data to the next, (including the 1st few passes), to see if perhaps the loss started higher and then reached this level, which would be totally normal. (If perhaps you're using a tiny amount of data, so several many passes over the data complete almost instantly, maybe you don't observe the early loss?)

Comment: @gojomo, I think you are right. I just use 3000 reports (about 240000 words) to training. thank you, I will extend my training data then try to watch the loss values over time again.